# Using an iterator to swap an element to the top of a linkedlist

Tags: java, time, linked-list, iterator

Currently I am working on a hospital queue system. I have a long called Time in the patient constructor. The time is set to the system.milliseconds. The method below is part of thread. It contains and iterator that gets the patient's time and compares it to the current system time. Once the patient's time reaches 2 minutes I want to move the element that has reached two minutes to the top of the queue. Every element that reaches 2 minutes should be moved to the top of the queue thereafter and ordered. The linkedlist is ordered by the patients severity automatically however if a patient is waiting too long they will be moved to the front. Hence the 2 minute intervals.

```
ListIterator<Patient> checktime = MainPatientQueue.patientslist.listIterator();

            while(checktime.hasNext()){

                Patient P = checktime.next();

                long max = 120000;
                long start = (P.getTime());



                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

                //System.out.println(end-start);





                if(end-start>max){



                    MainPatientQueue.patientslist.remove(P);

                    MainPatientQueue.patientslist.add(0, P);




                }



            }
```

Overall, I would like to know if there is a method that I can use within an iterator to move elements? Currently I am throwing a concurrent modification exception each time I try to move an element.

Thank you M Shaw. I have updated the code and it appears to work. However, When it moves the specific elements and returns to Patient P = checktime.next(); it throws an exception.

Comment: What is your question? Also, your code has LOTS of whitespace in - I'm reluctant to edit it until you edit your question to include a question.

Comment: Two questions: Why not using one of the [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) implementing classes? Why in general you would need to swap? If patient `A` arrives before patient `B` there would be never a reason to swat their priority order. Maybe I did not completely understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I saw you just edited your question to thank @M.Shaw - if his/her answer was helpful to you please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it so that (a) the community knows you are satisfied, and (b) M.Shaw will get some reputation for his/her efforts. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding the exception it seems that right way is to call `checktime.remove()` as it is not safe to directly remove an object from a Collection during an iteration as per javadocs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `patientslist` is an ArrayList or similar, you can remove the `Patient P` by `checktime.remove()` and add it to the start of the list by `patientslist.add(0, P)`.